# Creating xml based on html using xslt in java

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xhtml

Please help me i am doing project of file conversion that is converting xml to html using xsl in java and also i need to convert html to xml using the xsl. my first process is got over.but i structed in second part of conversion.. Is there is any possibility to do that conversion.I will tell you the exact flow of the first process...

This is my sample xml file:
**tabl.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xml" href="testxsl.xsl"?>
<mainpara>
<epigraph>
<para>Though successful research demands a deep
<emphasis role="italic">trained</emphasis> 
<emphasis role="italic">taught</emphasis> to regard.
</para>
<para>Kuhn (1976, p. 66)</para>
</epigraph>
<blockquote role="extract">
<para>Though successful research demands a deep commitment to the status quo.
<emphasis role="italic">trained</emphasis>
<emphasis role="italic">taught</emphasis> 
</para>
</blockquote>
</mainpara>
```

This is my sample xsl file:

**testme.xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
          xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="mainpara">
    <html>
    <body>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>     

  <xsl:template match="epigraph">
    <div>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="para">
    <p>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </p>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="blockquote">
    <b>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </b>
  </xsl:template>  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is my sample java file:

**Main.java**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class Main {  


    public static void simpleTransform(String sourcePath, String xsltPath,  
                                       String resultDir) {

        TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();  
        try {  
            Transformer transformer =  
                tFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(new File(xsltPath)));  

            transformer.transform(new StreamSource(new File(sourcePath)),  
                                  new StreamResult(new File(resultDir)));  

        } catch (Exception e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }  
    }  

    public static void main(String[] args) {  


        System.setProperty("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory",
                "net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl");

      simpleTransform("E:/bh/tabl.xml","E:/bh/testme.xsl", "E:/bh/me.html");
      //simpleTransform("E:/bh/me.html","E:/bh/11111.xsl","E:/bh/tab.xml" ); //This is i need

    }  
}
```

This is my generated html file:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <div>

         <p>Though successful research demands a deep commitment to the status quo, innovation
         </p>

         <p>Kuhn (1976, p. 66)</p>

      </div>
      <b>

         <p>Though successful research demands a deep commitment to the status quo
         </p>
         </b>

   </body>
</html>
```

Now i will edit this html file after edited this html file i need to convert this again to the xml file or xhtml file that is i need the reverse process. I think it is possible only by modifying the xsl. Is it possible to create the xsl based on that html.If i created that xsl file then i pass that xsl file in the above java program( i commented that line in the main java program).So i have to create that xsl file.

Please help me.. I need your help..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

**The reverse transformation can't be done**.

**Your transformation isn't lossless**. Among other things, you have lost the `emphasis` information -- it isn't reflected in the HTML output.

Answer (score 0):

Dimitre is, as always, correct but let me explain a bit more.

There's at least two issues here.

Firstly, you have text such as `<emphasis role="italic">trained</emphasis>` in your input XML that doesn't get output to your HTML. So there is absolutely no way that any tool or indeed person could reverse the transformation and guess what XML was used to generate the HTML. That's what Dimitre means by "Your transformation isn't lossless"

But let's assume that you changed your XSLT that turned the XML into HTML such that it was humanly possible to work out what the original XML was by looking at the HTML...

Secondly, the XLS to turn the HTML back into XML is going to be completely different to the XSL that turned the XML into HTML.

Did you code the XSLT shown in your question yourself? If not then the first thing that you need to do is try and understand that code. You'll never figure out a solution to your problem if you can't even understand this much.